# How to get new or refresh access token with wsfed for .net core?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, ws-federation, pingfederate

I am using wsfederation(with pingfederate as IDP) for authenticating.
This is working fine for getting access token first time, but when the token got expired, I need to get a new token or refresh token.
In .NET framework 4.7.2 it is working fine as we uses `WS2007FederationHttpBinding` and `WSTrustChannelFactory` to get new token.
But in .NET CORE I did not get any way to get the access token forcefully.

Do anyone have any idea on how do I get the new token by calling a API from my controller?

Comment: I'm stuck on the same problem.  I have code for requesting a token from STS in .NET Framework also using WSTrustChannelFactory but I've been unable to find the equivalent in .NET Standard.